# Gmail recognize a Reply-To email

Tags: git, email, gmail

```
git config --global sendemail.chainreplyto true
git format-patch -2 HEAD  -o patch --cover-letter
git send-email patch/* --to=ycsunjane@gmail.com
```

I can't figure out how to get gmail to recognize that an email was sent as a "Reply-To" by git and have those emails grouped together as one list of sent and replied emails.

[image: gmail]

```
Message-Id: <cover.1375354436.git.ycsunjane@gmail.com>
X-Mailer: git-send-email 1.8.3.4

Message-Id: <1375355476-9832-1-git-send-email-ycsunjane@gmail.com>
X-Mailer: git-send-email 1.8.3.4
In-Reply-To: <cover.1375354436.git.ycsunjane@gmail.com>
References: <cover.1375354436.git.ycsunjane@gmail.com>

Message-Id: <1375355476-9832-2-git-send-email-ycsunjane@gmail.com>
X-Mailer: git-send-email 1.8.3.4
In-Reply-To: <1375355476-9832-1-git-send-email-ycsunjane@gmail.com>
References: <cover.1375354436.git.ycsunjane@gmail.com> <1375355476-9832-1-git-send-email-ycsunjane@gmail.com>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would use something like

`git format-patch --thread ...`

to set the References and In-Reply-To headers. But gmail will not group emails that do not have the same subject (barring a few alterations such as adding RE:) The commit messages and the [patch n/m] will change for each patch in the series. So they will never be grouped.

The google support page states the following (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5900?hl=en)

> A conversation will break off into a new thread if the subject line of the conversation is changed, or if the conversation reaches over 100 messages.

So it does not seem like it is possible.

For what it's worth, I also found a link to a blog of someone who claims to have tested a few things regarding gmail conversation threading.

http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/08/how-does-email-threading-work-in-gmail.html

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out how to get gmail to recognize that an email was sent as a "Reply-To" by git

... by using the official SMPT field "`reply-to`": this is supported with Git 2.17 (Q2 2018): `--reply-to=<address>"` option.

See [commit d11c943](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d11c943c7824ed91ec396c8726d18ce687848d34), [commit 15dc3b9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15dc3b9161dad12e37d74863d0ab5d94b661a936) (03 Mar 2018) by [Christian Ludwig (`chludwig`)](https://github.com/chludwig).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e74737b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e74737b6a1d403bd0ad856bd23143ba0bd5dfabb), 15 Mar 2018)</sup>

> ### `send-email`: support separate `Reply-To` address

> In some projects contributions from groups are only accepted from a
> common group email address.

> But every individual may want to receive replies to her own personal address.

> That's what we have '`Reply-To`' headers for in SMTP.
> So introduce an optional '`--reply-to`' command-line option.

---

And with Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), when fed input that already has `In-Reply-To:` and/or `References:` headers and told to add the same information, "`git send-email`" added these headers separately, instead of appending to an existing
one, which is a violation of the RFC.
This has been corrected.

See [commit 256be1d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/256be1d3f0439b397a573f90868b8d09e11afbdf) (17 Apr 2018) by [Stefan Agner (`falstaff84`)](https://github.com/falstaff84).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c50f76a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c50f76aa9d40203650fe36107adbad42104f8cf6), 08 May 2018)</sup>

> ### `send-email`: avoid duplicate In-Reply-To/References

> In case a patch already has `In-Reply-To` or `References` in the header
> (e.g. when the patch has been created with `format-patch --thread`)
> `git-send-email` should not add another pair of those headers.

> This is also not allowed according to [RFC 5322 Section 3.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6).

> Avoid the second pair by reading the current headers into the
> appropriate variables.